# Column-Count Property is not working on Firefox

Tags: css, column-count

I have used the CSS3 multi-column feature, using the `column-count` property to split into multiple columns.

This is my code:

```
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

It's not working on my Firefox version or Firefox developer Edition. 
The code is working on: Google Chrome, Opera, and Microsoft Edge.

Is this a bug or is there any solution?

Comment: For me `column-fill: auto;` was causing this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to work on something similar a few years ago, and for what I remember, the cross-browser support wasn't bullet-proof (especially with older browsers) but this should work fairly well.

https://codepen.io/patriziosotgiu/pen/jGporg?editors=1100

Put the `column-break` in a container outside of the `ul` tag.
Also, in case you have to work on more complex layouts, a bunch of extra `break` properties may be helpful (See `li`).

Tested with latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari on Mac.

Note: Using flexbox would probably give you a better result, and a more up to date solution. It is worth trying it if your project can use flexbox.

Comment: You're more than welcome Nisarg, glad that it worked!

Comment: @Nisarg If it works, why don't you accept this answer. Let Patrizio enjoy the bounty points.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#search=Column-Count)

Firefox versions 55-59 have partial support for this feature:

> Partial support refers to not supporting the `break-before`,
>   `break-after`, `break-inside` properties. WebKit- and Blink-based browsers
>   do have equivalent support for the non-standard `-webkit-column-break-*`
>   properties to accomplish the same result (but only the `auto` and `always`
>   values). Firefox does not support `break-*`.

You'll need to post a code snippet displaying your issue if you require further assistance.

Comment: It's partial support for break-before,  break-after, break-inside properties, but not column-count. See: [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=column-count) Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add -moz-column-gap: 50px for the ul or the main container. It will fix the issue for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with issue in Mozilla Firefox v.97.0.1. Changing property to 'balance' worked in my case.

column-fill: balance;